# Unable to map a service layer entity to domain model entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, automapper, automapper-3

I am trying to get some data using one `GetData`. This business method is called from the controller through a service layer in this Action method:

```
public PartialViewResult Grid()
{
    var model = new DomainModels.Reports.MeanData();
    using (var reportsClient = new ReportsClient())
    {
        model = reportsClient.GetData(reportType, toDate, fromDate); //<= error on this line
    }
    return PartialView("_Grid", model);
}
```

I get this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   '`System.Collections.Generic.List<BusinessService.Report.MeanData>`' to
>   '`DomainModels.Reports.MeanData`'

A colleague had suggested using Automapper for this, so I changed the Action method like this, based on what worked for him:

```
public PartialViewResult Grid()
{
    using (var reportsClient = new ReportsClient())
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<DomainModels.Reports.MeanData, BusinessService.Report.MeanData>();
        var model = reportsClient.GetData(reportType, toDate, fromDate); 
        DomainModels.Reports.MeanData viewModel = //<= error on this line
            Mapper.Map<DomainModels.Reports.MeanData, BusinessService.Report.MeanData>(model);
    }
    return PartialView("_Grid", viewModel);
}
```

I get this error:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   '`AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<DomainModels.Reports.MeanData,BusinessService.Report.MeanData>`(DomainModels.Reports.MeanData)'
>   has some invalid arguments

The DomainModel entity:

```
[DataContract]
public class MeanData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Month3Value { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Month2Value { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Month1Value { get; set; }
}
```

The BusinessService entity, which can be found in the generated `reference.cs` is having properties with same names as the DomainModel entity.

What am I doing wrong in both instances?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: I tried your answer and got the error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<BusinessService.Report.MeanData>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<DomainModels.Reports.MeanData>'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reports client returns **list** of business entities and you are trying to map them to single entity. I think you should map collection of business entities to collection of view models (currently you are trying to map collection to single view model):

```
using (var reportsClient = new ReportsClient())
{
    List<BusinessService.Report.MeanData> model = 
        reportsClient.GetData(reportType, toDate, fromDate); 
    IEnumerable<DomainModels.Reports.MeanData> viewModel = 
        Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<DomainModels.Reports.MeanData>>(model);
}

return PartialView("_Grid", viewModel);
```

Move mapping creation to application start:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<DomainModels.Reports.MeanData, BusinessService.Report.MeanData>();
```

---

Also consider to use aliases if you have types with same name:

```
using BusinessMeanData = BusinessService.Reports.MeanData;
using MeanDataViewModel = DomainModel.Reports.MeanData;
```

Or (better) add `ViewModel` suffix to name of type which acts as view model. In this case code will look like:

```
using (var reportsClient = new ReportsClient())
{
    var model = reportsClient.GetData(reportType, toDate, fromDate); 
    var viewModel = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<MeanDataViewModel>>(model);
}

return PartialView("_Grid", viewModel);
```

Comment: @Animesh sorry, didn't notice you have two entities with same name. Now it should work. Don't forget to specify IEnumerable destination type when mapping collections with AutoMapper

Comment: Sorry, this didn't work. I spent the last couple of days trying to utilize this mapping, but it didn't work. I know this code is not wrong, but I ended up using the Service layer type as the model for the View (Deadline Oriented Development made me do it, sorry). Thanks for the insight anyway.